# azure function is not working in azure cloud but working in local. giving error in python script

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

```
import datetime
from distutils.log import log
import logging
import os
import azure.functions as func

def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()

    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)
    # os.system('echo "change directory to propertyscraper project"')
    # os.system('cd ./propertyscraper')
    # ROOT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
    os.system('echo "*****************************************************"')
    logging.info(os.getcwd())
    # os.system("echo $PWD")
    logging.info(f"curret dir: {os.getcwd()}" )

    os.system('echo "run airbnb spider"')
    path = os.path.join("scraped_json_files","airbnb.json")
    os.system(f"scrapy crawl airbnb -o {path}")
    logging.info(f"current dir files:{os.listdir()}")
    logging.info(f"previous dir files: {os.listdir('..')}")
    
    file_creation_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime(f'%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
    new_file_path = os.path.join("scraped_json_files","airbnb"+file_creation_time+".json")
    # os.rename(path, f"./scraped_json_files/airbnb{file_creation_time}.json")
    os.rename(path,new_file_path)
    # os.rename("./scraped_json_files/airbnb.json", "scraped_json_files/airbnb_"+file_creation_time+".json")
```

below is the error while I am running the azure function in azure. above code is working in my local system which is windows 10 but giving below error in azure. please help what am I doing wrong

```
Result: Failure Exception: OSError: [Errno 38] Function not implemented: 'scraped_json_files/airbnb.json' -> 
'scraped_json_files/airbnb2022-04-18_09-03-46.json' Stack: File 
"/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py"
, line 402, in _handle__invocation_request call_result = await self._loop.run_in_executor( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs) File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 611, in _run_sync_func return ExtensionManager.get_sync_invocation_wrapper(context, File "/azure-functions-
host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/extension.py", line 215, in _raw_invocation_wrapper result = function(**args) File 
"/home/site/wwwroot/scraper_timer_trigger/__init__.py", line 32, in main os.rename(path,new_file_path)
```

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue.

Comment: yes, It is a policy of azure function that whatever we deployed into wwwroot directory it can not be modified the content. so we can not rename or add new file in the directory.